# VAAPI version 1 on 18.04

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, 18.04, vaapi

Is there any way to get VAAPI v1.7.0 working in a Kubuntu 18.04 environment? An application I use specifically requires 1.7 as 2 has a different library version. I've tried installing packages from launchpad regarding libva and its drivers, but I still don't get reasonable results.

Comment: Hello, can you edit your question and add any relevant error messages you get when you try to install the application you need? Also add the application's package name. Are the errors happening during the ./configure stage? (I'm assuming you're building from source if the dependencies are for a different version of vaapi than the default one for 18.04.)

Comment: @Emily unfortunately it is a proprietary software so I can't build it from source. I'm having issues with Parsec, a software that does computer streaming. I used it fine on 16.04 which is the supported version, and the only thing stopping it from working on 18.04 is the libva library being too new in 18.04 as explained above. The developer when asked stated Parsec would not work above 1.7 as there is an explicit library version change.